# I tried to do welcome message with my discord bot (Using discord.js) And I have weird error

Tags: discord.js

I dont get what is wrong here in my code.
I used my token where I typed **my token goes here**

The error :

```
/home/runner/my-server-bot/index.js:43
client.login('I will hide my token');
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with that code?

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', msg => { // Commands Go Inside The client.on('message', 
msg =>
msg.guild.channels.get('861132489584934926').send({embed: {
color: 3447003,
author: {
  name: client.user.username,
  icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
},
title: "Welcome To OP COMMUNITY!",
description: "Have Fun in the server :)",
timestamp: new Date(),
footer: {
  icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
  text: "Builded by Oplikoo#9999"
} }

client.login('my token was here');
```

Comment: Please If anyone know what is the problem, so also explain me what I done wrong

Comment: What is the `client`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Probably because it's full of missing parentheses. Add `})})` before `client.login`. That won't be the only error though as you have two arrow functions with that `msg`...

Answer (score 1):

Your code was really messy! I decided to do a complete rework on it.
I explain how it works with notes in the code below.

```
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => { // We don't get msg from this, we get member.
            let channel = client.channels.get('861132489584934926'); // Getting the channel
    
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // A different form of making an embed
                .setAuthor({
                    name: client.user.username,
                    icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
                })
                .setColor('#447003')
                .setTitle('Welcome To OP COMMUNITY')
                .setDescription('Have Fun in the server :)')
                .setTimestamp(new Date())
                .setFooter({
                    icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
                    text: 'Builded by Oplikoo#9999'
                });
    
        channel.send(embed); // We send the embed we just created});
    });

client.login('my token was here');
```